# Fittonia Root Rot (Overwatered)

Tags: houseplants, watering, plant-care, transplanting, rot

[image][image]

I’ve had this plant for almost a year as my first plant. A few days ago I saw that it was starting to wilt, having had this issue before, I watered more, since the it usually wilted when I forgot to water it for an extended period. The wilting did not subside so I repotted it and started researching potential causes for this. I am now fairly certain that it is root rot from overwatering but would love a second opinion. I don’t know if the plants can still be saved. If it is not too late, what is the best course of action? Thanks

Comment: Healthy roots are more likely to be white and fat than brown and thin. To be honest I think it's gone to the great greenhouse in the sky. If I was feeling VERY lucky (or desperate) I might try cutting off all the roots except those like the one that looks light-coloured in the top photo, cut the stems just below the first leaf, dip the base of the plant in hormone rooting powder, and hope that fools it into thinking it is a cutting and it grows some more roots. But I wouldn't bet any money on success.

Comment: Thanks! I think I was too late in discovering the problem. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: The most important thing is drainage - Fittonia does not like to completely dry out, so its necessary to water fairly frequently - but the excess must be allowed to drain way freely from the base of the pot, and any outer pot emptied after 30 minutes so its not sitting in water... just in case you buy yourself a new one, though fairly similar rules apply to most houseplants.